# How to achieve the type-class of sml？

Tags: ocaml, sml, ml

I want to write a comparable set as below.

```
signature COMPARABLE_SET=
sig
  type 'a set
  val empty: 'a set
  val insert: 'a * 'a set -> 'a set
  val member: 'a * 'a set -> bool
end
```

I need to limit the element in 'a set type to be comparable：(there is a function with type:`'a * 'a -> order`).

How to achieve it?

Comment: Take a look at how the `ORD_SET` signature from the SML/NJ library is defined: http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/ord-set.html#ORD_SET:SIG:SPEC

Comment: Also, what you want can't be written in a safe way in SML. I've written two blog posts related to this topic: http://igstan.ro/posts/2017-04-08-a-safe-type-indexed-set-for-standard-ml.html and http://igstan.ro/posts/2017-04-12-a-safe-type-indexed-set-for-standard-ml-errata.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it in OCaml, this is simply a functor case :

First, you need to define the type of your elements :

```
module type OrderedType = sig 
  type t 
  val compare : t -> t -> int
end
```

And then you'll define a functor on this type :

```
module MakeComparableSet (Ord : OrderedType) :
  sig
    type elt = Ord.t
    type t
    val empty : t
    val insert : elt -> t -> t
    val member : elt -> t -> bool
  end = struct
    type elt = Ord.t
    type t
    let empty = failwith "TODO"
    let insert = failwith "TODO"
    let member = failwith "TODO"
  end
```

Which is exactly what is made [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.Make.html).

---

You can see a functor as a function on module that will create new modules. Here, the functor ComparableSet takes a module of signature OrderedType and returns a module that is a set.